# How do I use abstract model field values as default values in child model fields in Django?

Tags: python, django

For example,

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    foo_field = models.CharField(max_length=30)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True


class Bar(Foo):
    bar_field = models.CharField(max_length=30, default=Foo.foo_field)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

This code doesn't actually produce the results I want, but I think it illustrates the general idea. Basically, I want to take the value from `foo_field` and use it as a default value if no value is entered for `bar_field`.

I've tried returning `foo_field` with a `___str___` method in the Foo model and defining a variable in Bar with that value (i.e. `foo_field_value = Foo.foo_field`, but that didn't allow me to access the value either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

many possible solution

in save:

```
def save(self):
   if not self.bar_field:
      self.bar_field = self.foo_field
   super().save()
```

define methods:

```
  def get_bar_field(self):
      return self.bar_field or self.foo_field
```

signals:

```
@receiver(pre_save, sender=Bar)                                        
def assign_default_bar_field(sender, instance, **kwargs):                                 
   if not instance.bar_field:
       instance.bar_field = instance.foo_field
```

define clean methods:

```
def clean(self, data):
   if not 'bar_field' in data or not data['bar_field']:
      data['bar_field'] = data['foo_field']
   return data
```

Comment: Wow, thank you for all the different options. I really appreciate the help